# В каком виде хранить id пользователя?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Есть таблица пользователей:

```
Table Users:
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
     ...
```

Предлагают хранить не `id` а `uuid` в виде строки.
Потому что если светится `id 10`(http://www.example.com/customers/10/), то не трудно догадаться что есть и пользователь 11,12,...С чем я согласен.

Но и знаю тоже что MySQL для своей внутренней оптимизации все равно создает этот `id`. И так легко не хочу отказаться от него.

Думаю может какой нибудь алгоритм написать чтоб этот `id` форматировал в какую нибудь строку и наоборот, для таких случаев.

Как правильно поступать в таких случаев ?

Comment: Ну, будут знать, что у вас 100 пользователей. И? Это вроде не такая критичная информация, разве нет? По int'у, к примеру, шардить проще.

Comment: Во-первых, я тоже не вижу в id ничего секретного (если вы всё-таки считаете это секретным, будет полезно дописать в вопросе, почему, а то все ответы так и будут вида «uuid не нужен»). Во-вторых, ничего не мешает хранить id и uuid одновременно — наружу показывать только uuid, а для внутренних технических целей (внешние ключи, вышеупомянутый шардинг и т.п.) использовать стандартный id, который никому наружу не показывать

Comment: А вообще алгоритмы преобразования id в строку и обратно таки существуют, например https://hashids.org/ (но всё же я не вижу в этом смысла)

Comment: @Suvitruf По их мнению все таки критичная.Чем меньше информации тем лучше.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan id это не какие-нибудь персональные данные типа паспорта или номера мобильного, в большинстве случаев нет никакого смысла его прятать (к слову, ваш id на этом сайте — 207445, и чо)

Comment: @andreymal Также я  секьюрити говорю.Хочу окончательно разобраться с этим чтоб обосновать раз и навсегда.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan видимость id никак не влияет на секьюрити. Разве что может стоять цель скрыть реальное число пользователей, но, блин, зачем?

Comment: *если светится id 10(http://www.example.com/customers/10/)* А какого рожна, позвольте полюбопытствовать, оно светится?  Есть имя, есть идентификатор сессии... причём всё это можно гонять и без отображения в адресной строке.

Comment: @Akina ну вот тут, например, тоже почему-то светится → https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437

Comment: @andreymal Ну тут как бы вполне логично никого не коматозит, что другие знают твой идентификатор.

Comment: Благодарю всех за советы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если так боитесь за то, что узнают количество пользователей и т.п, то можете для всех операций с БД (внешние ключи, выборки и т.п.) оставить `INT`, но при создании записи помимо `INT`ового первичного ключа ещё сгенерить GUID поле. Вот его показывайте клиенту.

Для ускорения, на GUID поле вторичный индекс навесить можете. Или можете использовать какой-нибудь алгоритм конвертации `int <--> guid`.

Answer (score 0):

По сути можете генерировать ключ и как string, нету большой разницы, главное установить это поле как уникальный ключ, без AI, хотя не понимаю зачем Вам это, разве что можете генерировать ссылку как login-id, и проверять одно и второе значение, если Вы хотите скрывать пользователей.